# Selenium Unsupported Command Extension Problem

Tags: selenium, appium, appium-ios

I am getting the below error when i try to launch ios simulator in mac machine
unknown command: unknown command: wd/hub/session

Here are my capabilities.I want to launch safari browser in simulator but idont know why i am getting chrome-driver error?

```
  if(platform.equalsIgnoreCase("ios_safari")){
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 11");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "14.2");
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "safari");
    capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "XCUITest");
  /*capabilities.setCapability("xcodeOrgId","5P4WK7G4P6");
  capabilities.setCapability("xcodeSigningId","iPhone Developer");*/
    capabilities.setCapability("bundleId.BROWSER_NAME", "safari");
//        capabilities.setCapability("udid", "A0AE6E86-DDA7-44F4-B9B5-4057696122E3");
        capabilities.setCapability("udid", "1FBDD421-3913-45A2-961F-AC0ADAB574A5");


  }

  if(platform.equalsIgnoreCase("ios_chrome")){
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 11 Pro Max");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "14.0");
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "chrome");
    capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "XCUITest");
    capabilities.setCapability("xcodeOrgId", "myXcodeOrgId");
    capabilities.setCapability("bundleId.BROWSER_NAME", "chrome");
  }
```

Error:

> org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: unknown command:
> unknown command: wd/hub/session Build info: version: '3.141.59',
> revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03' System info: host:
> '', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:48c:b9cd:2422:f71f%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X',
> os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.15.7', java.version: '1.8.0_221'
> Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver remote stacktrace: 0
> chromedriver.exe                    0x000000010f914c29
> chromedriver.exe + 2464809 1   chromedriver.exe
> 0x000000010ff4f6f3 chromedriver.exe + 8996595 2   chromedriver.exe
> 0x000000010f759d56 chromedriver.exe + 650582 3   chromedriver.exe
> 0x000000010f6fa689 chromedriver.exe + 259721 4   chromedriver.exe
> 0x000000010f6fa34d chromedriver.exe + 258893 5   chromedriver.exe
> 0x000000010f6c01fa chromedriver.exe + 20986 6   chromedriver.exe
> 0x000000010f8e7830 chromedriver.exe + 2279472 7   chromedriver.exe
> 0x000000010f8f283a chromedriver.exe + 2324538 8   chromedriver.exe
> 0x000000010f8f24a7 chromedriver.exe + 2323623 9   chromedriver.exe
> 0x000000010f8ce945 chromedriver.exe + 2177349 10  chromedriver.exe
> 0x000000010f8f2d41 chromedriver.exe + 2325825 11  chromedriver.exe
> 0x000000010f8dcbda chromedriver.exe + 2235354 12  chromedriver.exe
> 0x000000010f6bdb85 chromedriver.exe + 11141 13  libdyld.dylib
> 0x00007fff70a61cc9 start + 1